# Invoke JS method from C# using SignalR?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, signalr, dom-events

I know there are lots of examples out there to do with SignalR but I can't seem to get it working, I was hoping that one of you may be able to show (in full) how a WebPage (threaded loop so we can see it happening over and over) could call a JS method on a Page and change a text label or create a popup or, just something so that we an see the method execute?

I'll give you my code and maybe you can point out the error, but any basic example of Server->Client invocation without a Client first making a request would be amazing!

Hub:

```
[HubName("chat")]
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients?
        Clients.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Calling (Threaded) method:

```
private void DoIt()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Chat>();
        hubContext.Clients.addMessage("Doing it... " + i);
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

JS:

```
$(function () {
    // Proxy created on the fly
    var chat = $.connection.chat;

    // Declare a function on the chat hub so the server can invoke it
    chat.addMessage = function (message) {
        confirm("Are you having fun?");
        confirm(message);
    };

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start();        
});
```

Comment: Are you able to make it work whitout the thread?

Comment: No, it just never executes the JS.  I even went to the extent of setting up a WCF service and calling that from a Winforms app with text and then having the service call the JS method, still didn't work.  No errors in Chrome console either...

Comment: Hmm... this looks ok upon cursory inspection. Do you see the connection actually get established in the network panel? What happens if you chain a .done(function () { alert("Connected!"); }); to the promise that is returned from start()? Does it fire? What if you put a textbox in the test page that actually calls chat.send() from the web page itself... do you see that message?

Comment: Have you been able to setup a simple echo service? What IIS are you using? IIS 7 on Windows 7 Home have connection concurrency problem.

Comment: @Allov - I'm using IIS 7 on Windows 7.  What should I do/change?

Comment: Use IIS Express. It can't be accessible from outside, but it's going to handle multiple connections.

Comment: @Allov - It doesn't work in Visual Studio either though...

Comment: It might have been user error... "<script type="text/javascript" src="/signalr/hubs"/>" is what I had and I forgot that most browsers don't support the self closing tag for JS imports... I'll do some more testing and confirm, but the "alert" popped up, which is a good sign! :)

Comment: Thank you both for your help, it turned out to be something that you had no visibility of.  So sorry about that!  I've posted my example here so that others who have are looking for an example of this architecture or are having similar issues can see.

Answer (score 3):

The issue I had was a self closing JS import tag which stopped all JS on the page being run...

For others who have the same issue, here is my working example on a Server pushing data out to all clients without any prompting from a client:

Javascript:

```
$(function () {
    // Proxy created on the fly
    var chat = $.connection.chat;

    // Declare a function so the hub can invoke it
    chat.addMessage = function (message) {
        document.getElementById('lblQuestion').innerHTML = message;
    };

    // Start the connection
    $.connection.hub.start();
});
```

HTML:

```
<h2 id="lblQuestion" runat="server">Please wait for a question...</h2>
```

Hub:

```
[HubName("chat")]
public class Chat : Hub
{
    public void Send(string message)
    {
        // Call the addMessage method on all clients
        Clients.addMessage(message);
    }

    public void Broadcast(string message)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Chat>();
        context.Clients.addMessage(message);
    }
}
```

Call to clients:

```
private void DoIt()
{
    int i = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        var hubContext = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<Chat>();
        hubContext.Clients.addMessage("Doing it... " + i);
        i++;
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

Threaded call to DoIt():

```
    var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoIt));

    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
```